# Display dates from array in a table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, momentjs

I have a problem where i want create an array of dates using moment.js and then display the contents of the array of dates in a table.

```
<table border="1">
  <tr ng-repeat="days in arr track by $index">
    <td ng-repeat="d in days track by $index">
        {{d}}
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Dates are created using moment and pushed to an array

```
var date = moment(),
begin = moment(date).startOf('week').isoWeekday(1);

var arr = [];
for (var i=0; i<35; i++) {
    arr.push(begin.format('D'));
    begin.add('d', 1);
}

$scope.arr = arr;
```

Frustratingly the above doesn't work as when the array is created it creates an individual array item for each digit (so 10 would be [1, 0...]) - I know I'm  making a silly mistake, but I'm not sure how or why.

Any help greatly appreciated - I hope this plunkr might make things clearer
https://plnkr.co/edit/HF0U9ZEPZVYTqS0Ss88c?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your problem is that you are actually looping with second ng-repeat loop through digits, I'm not sure if you want it like that but this could be solution - remove second loop:

```
<table border="1">
      <tr ng-repeat="days in arr track by $index">
        <td>
            {{days}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Here's plnkr:
https://plnkr.co/edit/Dv0nLdDImz5vzSDoWIIq?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for investigating. My rationale for the second loop was to enable a new row for the start of each week - https://plnkr.co/edit/HF0U9ZEPZVYTqS0Ss88c?p=preview